# Extracting sql data in ionic 5 without getting a ZoneAwarePromise

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, promise

Using the ionic 5 framework I am trying to extract data from my SQLite database using a function:

```
getGlobal(name, db) {
  console.log('... getting global');
        
  var result;
    
  sqlQuery = 'SELECT `value` FROM globals WHERE `name` = "' + name + '"';
  console.log('sql query: ' + sqlQuery); 
        
  result = db.executeSql(sqlQuery, []).then(value => {
    return JSON.parse(value.rows.item(0).value);
  });
        
  console.log('return: ', result);
        
  return result;
}
```

I have tried even further ".then(data => {})" chaining to extract the correct result but withoug success. Always produces a ZoneAwarePromise.

Not sure where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the function itslef. Even converting it to an async function with ***await*** will return a fullfilled promise.

At the receiving end, eg

```
getGlobal('variable', db)
```

extract the value by adding

```
.then(value => console.log(value));
```

This is me learning more about promises. Maybe this answer is helpful to others.